# Formatting while writing to a text file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have an array which looks like this:

```
    cloud =

7.5059   51.4406
7.5057   51.4445
7.5048   51.4484
7.5034   51.4522
7.5014   51.4558
7.4989   51.4593
7.4958   51.4627
7.4923   51.4658
7.4884   51.4686
.
.
```

all i want is to write this array to a text file as it is, in the same format. I tried both `fprintf` and `dlmwrite`but i'm able to produce the exact same format. I know its an easy one, but I'm only asking after trying a lot.

Comment: What is your code with `dlmwrite`, it should be working I guess.

Comment: something like '7.4081,51.127.4078,51.1257.4068,51.1297.4053,51.1337.4032,51.137'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked into [string formatting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html)?

```
fid = fopen( 'myFile.txt', 'w' );
for ii=1:size(cloud,1)
    fprintf( fid, '%.5g\t%.5g\r\n', cloud(ii,1), cloud(ii,2) );
end
fclose( fid ); % do not forget to close the file :-)
```

Have you considered [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html)ing into ascii file?

```
save( 'myFile.txt', 'cloud', '-ascii', '-tabs' );
```

**EDIT:**

1. End-of-line issue: for text file there are several way of marking the end of line: On windows it is usually required to print `\r\n`, for Mac and Linux sometimes it is enough to use `\r` and sometimes `\n` (I'm not 100% sure). So, you might need to experiment with it a bit to find out what works best for your machine. (Thanks @Rody for correcting me here)
2. Accuracy: the number in the formatting string `%.5g` determines the accuracy of the printed number. Again, you can play with it till you are satisfied with the results.

Comment: It coming like this - 8.833 51.098.832 51.098.832 51.098.831...and somehow it truncated my values too.

Comment: It's the other way around. *nix uses `\n` while Windows uses `\r\n`

Answer (score 2):

### WINDOWS

Here's one way:

```
fid = fopen('cloud.txt', 'w');    
fprintf(fid, '%.4f\t%.4f\r\n', cloud.');
fclose(fid)
```

Here's the more readable way:

```
dlmwrite('cloud.txt', cloud, 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', 4, 'newline', 'pc')
```

### LINUX

Here's one way:

```
fid = fopen('cloud.txt', 'w');    
fprintf(fid, '%.4f\t%.4f\n', cloud.');
fclose(fid)
```

Here's the more readable way:

```
dlmwrite('cloud.txt', cloud, 'delimiter', '\t', 'precision', 4);
```

Comment: first one `cloud =8.0775   50.9617   8.0773   50.9646    8.0766   50.9675`
    `

Comment: second one prints the second column below the first

Comment: third one - gives the error `Error using dlmwrite (line 118)`is not a valid attribute or delimiter. Delimiter must be a single character.

Comment: So i tried with single space but again it prints the rows horizontally.

Comment: @Vikram: Let me guess: Windows user? :) Wait a second, I'll make the necessary adjustments.

Comment: Yeah..and please explain if possible how can windows is making the difference here.

Comment: @Vikram: There, that should do it. I removed the first one (it was more like a joke anyway), and adjusted the second one so it works on Windows. The third one I just typed without testing, so I missed the error. Should work OK now (at least here on my Windows machine)

Comment: @Vikram: Windows treats new lines differently. In Windows you have to give a carriage return (`\r`) before the newline (`\n`). In *nix, only a newline (`\n`). An annoying difference that all too easily messes things up. Read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23366/discussion-between-vikram-and-rody-oldenhuis)